# Running eclipse from a network file system

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ide, nfs

How does eclipse perform when running directly from a [network file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) on linux?

**Use case**:
We do not want to install eclipse in local drives as of now as upgrades and maintenance become overhead (we'll head to this eventually). However, we still want to have control on the eclipse edition being used (this includes couple of other default settings, plugin installations, and preferences that we want developers to adhere to). One possible solution is to put the tar in a network location and let people copy that and run locally. But this makes upgrades to this eclipse bundle difficult. We would rather want to put the exploded eclipse folder in the shared NFS and let people run directly from there (and control upgrades via symlinks).

**Concern**:
Does eclipse load all the plugins at the time of startup? If yes, the only possible impact could be the startup time. If not, then there can be latencies in various operations being performed later.

Please note, workspace is still going to be on a local drive. Yes we can try this out, but I don't want that a good network bandwidth available right now (which can get bad due to increased network traffic) gives false results, and so want to confirm the behavior.